# How to inject client configuration into a WPF client class

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, wsdl, client

I'm writing a console application that needs to connect to an external SOAP service. I ran the connected service scripts from Visual Studio, and was presented with a bunch of code in a `Reference.cs` file. There's a class called `TheirServiceClient`, which is the client I want to use. The service uses Basic Authentication, so `base64(User:Password)`, though I'd expect the framework to handle that part for me (maybe this assumption is where I'm going wrong).

The client class has a partial with this comment:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
/// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);
```

This looks to me like I can create my own partial class and method and... do something with the credentials.

I've also found this article on Microsoft explaining how to implement custom credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/walkthrough-creating-custom-client-and-service-credentials

However, it looks like it's more complicated than what I need to do.

Is there a strait forward way to inject ClientCredentials into this generated class?

Comment: For soap i think in the past i set up the bindings rather like WCF with basic authentication. Then set properties in the client when making the call like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication

Answer (score 0):

The link @Andy posted is more complete, but it's pretty strait forward:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Username = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```